#  Endpoints address issue

Tags: wcf, endpoint

I have a WCF Service named DataService which is hosted in IIS in DataService Virtual Directory. Its location is `http://localhost:5555/DataService`

When I configure endpoints what should I write in the address of the endpoint?

For example `http://localhost:5555/DataService/MyService/`

Is MyService physical in existence or it is virtual and just for the client so that client can communicate using this endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not make sense.

The endpoint is virtual in the same way that a website URL is virtual. You can't see it; it's a resource locator. My home address is also 'virtual', it's not physical - the building is physical, but the building is not the address.

Further, everything we do in software is virtual. An application is not a 'physical' thing.

Perhaps you are asking whether a Virtual Directory affects the way your service works. The answer to that question is **NO**, it does not.

You might find the following article on MSDN helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210%28v=vs.90%29.aspx